# Filter results by id or name

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I don't have alot of experience with php (i'm a newb) so bear with me here:

My problem is this... i have this script, i has a bookmark option, i want to display a list of bookmarked items, currently the list of bookmarks is saved this way:

http://s25.postimg.org/3y03mhjl7/screenshot_caiman_arvixe_com_2083_2015_02_02_16.png

as you can see in the image user #2 has bookmarked item 13 and 7...

here is a sample of the code for the bookmark list page:

```
    <?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM manga_mangas ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 10");
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $i += '1';
  $description = stripslashes($row['description']);
  $poptitle = stripslashes($row['name']).' '.($row['released'] != NULL ? '('.$row['released'].')' : '');
?>
      /* 
      <span class="custom-thumbnail" data-toggle="mangapop" data-placement="left" manga-slug="<?=$row['slug']?>" data-original-title="<?=$poptitle?>">
        <div class="media">
          <a class="pull-left" href="<?=$lang['manga_slug']?>-<?=$row['slug']?>.html">
            <span class="custom-container-popular2"><img class="media-object img-thumb" src="<?=$row['cover']?>" alt="<?=$row['name']?>" width="85px"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <div style="margin: 0 0 5px 0"><b class="media-heading" id="tables"><a href="<?=$lang['manga_slug']?>-<?=$row['slug']?>.html"><?=$row['name']?></a></b></div>
            <b><?=$lang['Views'] ?>:</b> <?=$row['views']?><br />
            <?php if($row['last_chapter'] != 0){ ?><b><?=$lang['Last_chapter']?>:</b> <a href="<?=$lang['read_slug']?>-<?=$row['slug']?>-<?=$lang['chapter_slug']?>-<?=$row['last_chapter']?>.html"><?=$row['last_chapter']?></a><br /><?php } ?>
            <b><?=$lang['Authors']?>:</b> <?=$row['authors']?><br />
            <b><?=$lang['Artists']?>:</b> <?=$row['artists']?><br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>

<? } ?>
```

currently that code only displays a list of  the first 10 most viewed items, it doesn't filter them using the users bookmarks, how do i filter them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly something similar to the following should work.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT mm.* FROM manga_mangas AS mm INNER JOIN bookmarked_items AS bi ON mm.id=bi.manga WHERE bi.user=".mysql_escape_string($userId)." ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 10");
```

You didn't specify the rest of your database structure so you'll need to replace the table names and field names with your correct ones.